# Anti-XSS script does not work, or is there a better method?

Tags: php, html, security, xss

I've been struggling with a certain script, its a function combination of 3 functions used in PHP to "clean"  or " scrub" inputs in forms from special characters, white spaces and slashes/backslashes.

Problem is, it doesnt seem to work, which is really weird, since I reviewed the PHP official page about it, W3schools, and stack overflow, and didn't come up with an answer to why it might not work, since I *THINK* I have the right format for the functions.

but i could be mistaken, i am a young student without much knowledge after all.

here's the function I talked about:

```
<?php       
    $data = clean_data('d/ in\ g<script>e %&*$^s #% ');

    function clean_data($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
    echo $data;
?>
```

the random stuff inside of the `'` symbols on the second line is the input (same result when i use it with my form), its to test, of course, in reality, there would be the `$_POST` function, getting the data from the form, and put it in another variable (called differently then `$data`).

I would be thankful if someone can point me into the right direction :)

**EDIT:**
THanks to some very usefull comments, i learned what certain functions in my script really do, and after gettig pointed out that the script somehow works for everybody else except me, leaves me mistefied, so if anyone else has a suggestion if there is a better way to "prevent", or atleast minimize XSS attacks by implenting security in my PHP script (sanitizing entities for example), that would be appriciated

Comment: What *exactly* doesn’t seem to work?

Comment: The whole thing, after scanning the code by using the echo function to see what is the input and output after each function, nothing changes, it absolutely doesnt do a thing

Comment: Did you consider that the web browser interprets the response as HTML? I mean, did you look at the source code?

Comment: When I run it, the input and output are different. (It still sucks, you can't apply a generic "fix everything" clean up script to any text, and it tries to solve three different problems, at least one of which shouldn't apply to any input anyway).

Comment: @ Gumbo, this is PHP, the browser doesnt interprate anything, @ Quentin, its used to filter certain characters in a form, to prevent XSS, the form is used to submit simple data to a database

Comment: @Lighty Then how do you invoke the mentioned code? Via command line?

Comment: @Gumbo, no, the form has an action referring to function.php, which has the php script for all the things, including this code, in POST method ofcourse

Comment: @Lighty Form, POST? So you are running the code with a web browser. Anyway, have a look at this [code fiddle](http://ideone.com/Axbfnq), which proves that `$data === 'd/ in g&lt;script&gt;e %&amp;*$^s #%'`.

Comment: @Gumbo then why doesnt it work on my side? that what you just said was the htmlspecialchars and stripslash, but not the trim for whitespaces...

Comment: that fiddle shows trimming as well.

Comment: i still see whitespaces

Comment: @Lighty What output do you expect?

Comment: from     ('d/ in\ g<script>e %&*$^s #% ');
i excpect something alike    ('d/ing&lt;script&gt;e%&amp;*$^s#%')
and i tested your fiddle on the test enviorment, doesnt have any difference with my script

Comment: @Lighty Then you misunderstand what [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) does. Just read the [manual page](http://php.net/trim).

Comment: it doesnt strip whitespaces in the string?

Comment: @Lighty Just read it: "Strip whitespace (or other characters) **from the beginning and end of a string**"

Comment: i should hang a donkey tail on mah pants and some fluffy ears for the rest of the day... still doesnt explain why it wont work :/.....whats with the vardump if i may ask?

Comment: @Lighty **Read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/)!!**

Comment: a great portion of this script is **LITERALLY TAKEN** from the W3school and PHP site, and double checked there, it needs to work, what did you do to make it work for you?

Comment: @Lighty Your expectation is just wrong as `trim` does only remove whitespace at the beginning and the end of the string, but not in between.

Comment: "its used to filter certain characters in a form, to prevent XSS," — Wrong. The first part removes white space from the start and end. That doesn't help with XSS. The second part removes ``\`` characters. That breaks input unless you have a badly configured PHP installation that has magic quotes turned on (and then you have to use it only on data that has been touched by magic quotes). The third part does actually deal with XSS, but only if you are about to insert it into an HTML document as part of an element content or in an attribute value delimited with double quotes.

Comment: To get the script to work for me, I just ran it with PHP.

Comment: "TAKEN from the W3school and PHP site" — W3Schools is awful and is written by people who don't appear to understand security. That code doesn't look like any part of the PHP manual other then *comments* by anybody who felt like weighing in with a comment and should be taken with a pinch of salt.

Comment: a pile of salt if you ask me, since i dont take things from random strangers without something of a profile to judge if i should trust the advice or not, but this all doesnt awnser the question, WHy doesn't this work? or what i seem to hear, why does this all work for you, but not for me?

Comment: The only reasons I can think of are that you don't have PHP configured properly or you are misinterpreting the results of your tests.

Comment: And then there was UTF-7... (websecurity is more than striping some slashes and characters from user input strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to this much effort... you are doing it wrong.

Here are a few contexts where user input must be handled with care, and the *correct* way to handle them:

1. **HTML**. Anything the user inputs that is sent to the browser is interpreted by said browser as HTML. As such, care must be taken to prevent users from injecting code of their choice. Luckily, it's quite simple. [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) will escape all the necessary characters to ensure that whatever the user typed is what they get back.<sup>1</sup>
2. **JavaScript**. Sometimes you may need to drop a variable from PHP into JavaScript. Whether or not it contains user input, you must be careful that you generate valid JavaScript. Luckily, [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) is practically designed for that. Give it a variable and it will output it in a way that JavaScript will understand flawlessly. Strings will have quotes added and characters within will be suitably escaped.
3. **MySQL**. Perhaps the most argued over, and yet the easiest one to get right! If (and *only* if) you are stuck maintaining ancient code, you can use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) to sanitise your input and prevent SQL injection, but really you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)'s prepared statements feature. Like `json_encode` above, prepared statements just take a variable and do all the hard work for you!
4. **PHP**. Just... don't use `eval` with user input. Ever. Okay?
5. **Bash/Shell**. Use of [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell-exec) and related functions with user input is rare, but just in case you happen to need it, be sure to always wrap arguments in [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg). This, again, handles automatic quoting of strings and escaping of dangerous characters.

Overall, there are built-in, simple ways to do things based on the context you are in. There is no catch-all solution because the contexts are all different with their different rules. Restricting what a user can type in is bad, especially when it's so easy to allow arbitrary input in a safe manner.

<sup>1: Spaces will still be collapsed, just like if you type several spaces in the source code. This can be left as desired behaviour, or fixed with the CSS `white-space: pre-wrap;`. Consider also `word-wrap: break-word;` to ensure that people don't enter stupidly long words to break your layout.</sup>

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` should be `mysqli_real_escape_string` to avoid referencing deprecated methods.

Comment: @h2ooooooo "ancient code" wouldn't be using `mysqli` ;)

Comment: Ah - very true. I missed that part and got tics just by staring at `mysql_real_escape_string` :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i noted this in my report (for this study) :3, and i secured the database with a maxlength for the fields that need one (like age, name, date etc.), while the form itself has maxlengthtags to let regular users type everything in without screwing up layout (got the twotter-bootstrap framework for that ;3 ), so youre suggesting the script i currently want to fix, isnt the best way to approach XSS attacks on things im making?

Comment: @Lighty Why is age a field that needs a max length? Isn't it it an unsigned `TINYINT` like it should be? Isn't `date` a `DATE` type?

Comment: @Lighty `maxlength` is not a security thing. Anyone can submit anything they want, they do not have to go through the arbitrary forms you have created for them. The script you posted in your question is *destructive*, and should not be used.

Comment: with 3 numbers, its to minimize any collisions or damage to the database, in event of an abuse, just useless safety tips i got at school i guess

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol what do you mean destructive? is there a better way to filter the input in the PHP script from characters to minimize the risk of XSS?

Comment: @Lighty Yeah, either your school is useless or you completely misunderstood ;) Age should be a `TINYINT UNSIGNED` field.

Comment: @Lighty I mean "destructive" in that you are removing things that have been typed. If I type something into your system, I expect either an error telling me I can't do that, otherwise the *exact* same output should arrive. Failure to do that is destroying the user's input.

Comment: ohh, so the best way to do this is make like, a validation script, that scans the output, and instead of filtering, returns an error to the user if certain characters are used, and stop the rest of the script?